# Recyclerview is not showing unless i focus the edittext

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment (i tried also in activity) that have edittext and button and recyclerview
I expect to get json data displayed in the recyclerview after clicking the button to search with the text
of edittext.

problem is:
it works fine but i should press my edittext

here is the button clicklistener code :

```
searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
 hospsAdapter = new hospsAdapter(getContext(), arrayList, HospitalFragment.this);

    
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);



    recyclerView.setAdapter(hospsAdapter);
loadData()
}
}
```

inside the load data method i call this method after getting json data from volley

```
public void updateList(ArrayList<HospitalsModel> list){
    if(hospsAdapter != null) {
        hospsAdapter.updateData(list);
    }
}
```

And here is the adaper code:

```
 public class hospsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<hospsAdapter.OrdersViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private ItemClickHandler itemClickHandler;
    private List<HospitalsModel> orderDetailsList;
    HospitalsModel productsModel;
    

    public hospsAdapter(Context context, List<HospitalsModel> orderDetailsList , ItemClickHandler itemClickHandler) {

        this.context = context;
        this.itemClickHandler = itemClickHandler;
        this.orderDetailsList = new ArrayList<>(orderDetailsList);
               }

    public hospsAdapter() {
    }
    public interface ItemClickHandler{
        public void onItemClick(HospitalsModel productsModel);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public OrdersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.hosps_list_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new OrdersViewHolder(view);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OrdersViewHolder ordersViewHolder, int i) {
        HospitalsModel productsModel = orderDetailsList.get(i);
        Glide.with(context).load(productsModel.getImageUrl()).into(ordersViewHolder.appCompatImageView);
        ordersViewHolder.orderTv.setText(productsModel.getName());
        ordersViewHolder.orderTv2.setText("العنوان: "+productsModel.getAddress());
        ordersViewHolder.orderTv5.setText("متاح الان: نعم"+"");
        final int[] flag = {1};
        ordersViewHolder.appCompatImageView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(flag[0] ==1) {
                    ordersViewHolder.appCompatImageView2.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.heart2));
                    flag[0] = 2;
                }else {
                    ordersViewHolder.appCompatImageView2.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.heart));
                    flag[0] =1;
                }


            }
        });
       ordersViewHolder.book.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
             dialPhoneNumber(productsModel.getOpenHo(),context);
           }
       });
        ordersViewHolder.map.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" +productsModel.getName());
                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(v.getContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    v.getContext().startActivity(mapIntent);
                }
            }
        });




    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return orderDetailsList.size();

    }
    public void updateData(List<HospitalsModel> movies) {
        orderDetailsList.clear();
        this.orderDetailsList = movies;
      notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
   
    public class OrdersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
@BindView(R.id.order_img)
AppCompatImageView appCompatImageView;
        @BindView(R.id.fav_img)
        AppCompatImageView appCompatImageView2;
@BindView(R.id.order_tv4)
TextView orderTv2;
        @BindView(R.id.order_tv)
        TextView orderTv;
        @BindView(R.id.order_tv5)
        TextView orderTv5;
        @BindView(R.id.button_more)
        Button book;
        @BindView(R.id.button_map)
        Button map;
        public OrdersViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this,itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            HospitalsModel productsModel = orderDetailsList.get(position);
            itemClickHandler.onItemClick(productsModel);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

        public void dialPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber,Context context) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 22) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((DoctorsActivity)context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, 101);

                return;
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
            if (intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
            if (intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
               context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
        }
```

I've tried every thing in every related question but no thing changed
so please help and tell me why can this problem happen while android development.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i found a solution for this issue
after updating the adapter list create a handler and refresh your layout

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerView).invalidate();
                                getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerView).requestLayout();
                            }
                        },1500);
```

Comment: you can increase the handler duration as you need

Comment: for me i set it to 3000 ms

Comment: why this is happening because query is loading data, after layout of the screen loaded. if you keep recyclerview height to match_parent also will solve problem instead of using handler,because handler is deprecated

Comment: @MohdQasim I have set recyclerview's height to match_parent, but its still not working.

Comment: @Pooja share your layout may be parent view of recyclerview is wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in your code, try to fix them first.

1- Initialize your adapter and layout manager in `onCreate` (activity) or `onViewCreated` (fragment).

2- Just `loadData()` must be called when your button is clicked

3- Your `updateList(...)` must be called on your UI thread

4- Try to clear all items in your `orderDetailsList` then add new items on it

Anyway there are better solutions to handle such these things and that are MVI or MVVM.
You can continue learning Android from here [Android Doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide)

Update Answer :

Your adapter seems good, however apply these two things.

1- Remove `List<HospitalsModel> orderDetailsList` argument in your constructor and initialize `orderDetailsList` without any initial items.

2- Try to replace `updateData(...)` with this one,

```
public void updateData(List<HospitalsModel> movies) {
  orderDetailsList.clear();
  orderDetailsList.addAll(movies);
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mehdi thanks for your reply
i moved the initialization code to onCreateView and only loadData() is called inside onClick method and
i have cleared the list before populating and 
called updatelist from getActivity.runOnUiThread method 
but nothing changes , i tried these solutions before but recyclerview not showing unless focusing edittext

Comment: it is clear that notifyDataSetChanged not working until pressing edittext  but i don't know why

Comment: The data you provide on your question is not sufficient.
@ابانوبعاطف

Comment: when i add list.addAll it shows nothing but when i assign new arraylist by = operator it doesn't show the data till clicking the edittext @Mehdi

Comment: Thank you very much @Mehdi for your interest and help

Comment: Anytime,
Your codes should work.However instead of using legendary Adapter use https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter

@ابانوبعاطف